# Policy document parsing error: Lexical Error: Unmatched Input: <'>

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-storage

i'm trying to set up file upload to google cloud storage using Policy doument.

ref: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object#policydocument

**Policy document**

```
{"expiration": "2020-06-16T11:11:11Z",
 "conditions": [
  ["starts-with", "$key", "" ],
  {"acl": "bucket-owner-read" },
  {"bucket": "cli201509.appspot.com"},
  {"success_action_redirect": "http://cli201509.appspot.com/getpolicydocumentsuccess" },
  ["eq", "$Content-Type", "image/jpeg" ],
  ["content-length-range", 0, 1000000]
  ]
}
```

**HTML FORM**

```
<form action="http://storage.googleapis.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="key" value="cli201509.appspot.com/texst/textasad.jpg">
<input type="hidden" name="bucket" value="cli201509.appspot.com">
<input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg">
<input type="hidden" name="GoogleAccessId" value="cli201509@appspot.gserviceaccount.com">
<input type="hidden" name="acl" value="bucket-owner-read">
<input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://cli201509.appspot.com/getpolicydocumentsuccess">
<input type="hidden" name="policy" value="eydjb25kaXRpb25zJzogW1snc3RhcnRzLXdpdGgnLCAnJGtleScsICcnXSwgeydhY2wnOiAnYnVja2V0LW93bmVyLXJlYWQnfSwgeydidWNrZXQnOiAnY2xpMjAxNTA5LmFwcHNwb3QuY29tJ30sIHsnc3VjY2Vzc19hY3Rpb25fcmVkaXJlY3QnOiAnaHR0cDovL2NsaTIwMTUwOS5hcHBzcG90LmNvbS9nZXRwb2xpY3lkb2N1bWVudHN1Y2Nlc3MnfSwgWydlcScsICckQ29udGVudC1UeXBlJywgJ2ltYWdlL2pwZWcnXSwgWydjb250ZW50LWxlbmd0aC1yYW5nZScsIDAsIDEwMDAwMDBdXSwgJ2V4cGlyYXRpb24nOiAnMjAyMC0wNi0xNlQxMToxMToxMVonfQ==">
<input type="hidden" name="signature" value="I+jU4464Q7MxYQLl3qeRmrMi98VV5heiYnLMUYhb71Z3aozvwkLU3lfnatg0VAi3/plaQXF3hW93qMduodZ2e3NjRpOW9AYNMs611y2GMGinzEuLtu7h88n5In4ZhNHyOS4jM/xs+ITy1izILjTDHk0JTq1RE2Wb3MXaTWwTjHpwC97YQuTZTBfGEPUwz0tHP21eVlUX+NuC7FpWttskJJ2hheV5yUe0a8PCDYL6WXWlTgKpDbtH0ceMuJJUlVaxH4HN7vC7azes7xRYxgdkeOsrbgRpVbCCgeJQQwcogRk/ZVV1DGS7h6DNAAid69WknrmCNI+KAgLprKXavFQ/uA==">

<input name="file" type="file">
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

**Error Response**

```
<Error><Code>InvalidPolicyDocument</Code>
<Message>The content of the form does not meet the conditions specified in the policy document.</Message>
<Details>Policy document parsing error: Lexical Error: Unmatched Input: &lt;'&gt;</Details>
</Error>
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the exact syntax you are using to upload the files to the bucket? probably it would be easier to give away the policy document as a JSON file

Comment: "{'expiration': '2020-06-16T11:11:11Z', 'conditions': [  ['starts-with', '$key', '' ],  {'acl': 'bucket-owner-read' },  {'bucket': 'cli201509.appspot.com'}, {'success_action_redirect':'http://cli201509.appspot.com/getpolicydocumentsuccess' },  ['eq', '$Content-Type', 'image/jpeg' ],  ['content-length-range', 0, 1000000]  ]}"

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I meant for the whole HTTP request using the POST method.

Comment: i'm using the html form describe in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reviewed the JSON and I've discovered it is not correctly formatted.

This is the one you are using,

```
"{'expiration': '2020-06-16T11:11:11Z', 'conditions': [ ['starts-with', '$key', '' ], {'acl': 'bucket-owner-read' }, {'bucket': 'cli201509.appspot.com'}, {'success_action_redirect':'cli201509.appspot.com/getpolicydocumentsuccess'; }, ['eq', '$Content-Type', 'image/jpeg' ], ['content-length-range', 0, 1000000] ]}"
```

Nonetheless, the correct version should replace all single apostrophes for double ones (" instead of ').

```
{
    "conditions": [
        ["starts-with", "$key", ""], {
            "acl": "bucket-owner-read"
        }, {
            "bucket": "cli201509.appspot.com"
        }, {
            "success_action_redirect": "http://cli201509.appspot.com/getpolicydocumentsuccess"
        },
        ["eq", "$Content-Type", "image/jpeg"],
        ["content-length-range", 0, 1000000]
    ],
    "expiration": "2020-06-16T11:11:11Z"
}
```

Once I execute the HTML form it does throw me an incorrect key error, which means the unbalanced statement has been solved. Can you verify if it works for you?

Comment: yes, it solves the issue. but `'` or `"` both should be working.